# Netbeans 7.0.1 missing display window

Tags: java, netbeans

SInce a few days, my Netbeans application window is missing from the screen. When I try to launch it, only the application icon appears in the launcher, but when I click on it, nothing happens.

When I try to launch it from a terminal command, no errors are returned. I also tried to reinstall, but the problem remains.

Comment: i am using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: How did you install netbeans? Did you try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall netbeans`?

Comment: i reinstalled using ubuntu softwear center

Comment: So, if you run it from the terminal everything works as expected? Or you just don't get any clue about the problem?

Comment: if i run it from terminal still nothing happens also Terminal don't show error messages